# How to display text as number of UIViews as a ULabel with each addition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Currently I have created a  draggable UIView as a subview that currently displays the text inside of it with each creation. However, I want the text inside of it to change with each creation such as the first UIView displays 1, the second displays 2, and the third displays 3, etc. Here is my code thus far:

```
- (void)panWasRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner {

{

UIView *draggedView = panner.view;

CGPoint offset = [panner translationInView:draggedView.superview];
CGPoint center = draggedView.center;
draggedView.center = CGPointMake(center.x + offset.x, center.y + offset.y);
draggedView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
draggedView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0f;


// Reset translation to zero so on the next `panWasRecognized:` message, the
// translation will just be the additional movement of the touch since now.
[panner setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:draggedView.superview];

}




}



- (IBAction)addRepButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)newRep {

buttonCount ++;
if (buttonCount > 1 )
{



    UILabel *textField = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    [textField setBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    textField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 4.0f;
    textField.text = @"1";
    textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];







UIPanGestureRecognizer *panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panWasRecognized:)];
[textField addGestureRecognizer:panner];




}


}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a property on the class, which keeps a count of the number of labels.  So in the interface (header file, or you can add an interface at the top of the main file) add an integer property, like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger labelCounter;
```

Initialize the counter to zero in your viewDidLoad method, eg :

```
self.labelCounter = 0;
```

Now in your addRepButton method, set the label text to be the value of that number, like this :

```
textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.labelCounter];
```

And within the same method, increment your counter for the next label :

```
self.labelCounter++;
```

That should do it.

Comment: One more question, would you happen to know how to keep the number sequence going if I were to delete one of these uiviews? for example: I add 1,2,3,4, and 5 to the view controller. But, I delete 4 and 5. How do I code it so the next number is 4 instead of 6?

Comment: Well thats a little more complicated.  You see, you could potentially delete labels 1 and 3, leaving 2,4 and 5.  So what should your next number be : 1, or 3, or 6?  Either way - you need to keep an array of the values on screen.  Quite alot more code, more than Ive room for here!  Consider instead, having a remove button.  Have a property on the view again, but this one for the 'lastLabel' added.  On remove clicked, do [self.lastButton removeFromSuperview] to remove it.  Then, do self.labelCounter--; to lower that count again.  Hope thats enough of a clue, good luck.

Comment: any chance you would know how to do the integer counting for a draggable button?

Comment: for some reason when I implement this into the button it only repeatedly gives me the number 1